# Outlook Addin displayNewAppointmentForm function not works in AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface Extension Point

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I am working on creating a new appointment form with parameters using ExecuteFunction. It's working on

**`AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface`**

Extension point but not works on

**`AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface`**

Extension point.

I couldn't find it on [this site](https://dev.office.com/documentation). Is it possible **`displayNewAppointmentForm`** 
on both Extension points?

```
function openAppFrm(event) 
{
    var start = new Date();
    var end = new Date();
    end.setHours(start.getHours() + 1);

    Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm(
        {
            requiredAttendees: ['kamal@abc.com', 'nimal@abc.com'],
            optionalAttendees: ['kasun@abc.com'],
            start: start,
            end: end,
            location: 'Colombo Office',
            subject: 'Test Meeting',
            body: 'Hello World!'
        });
    event.completed();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for letting us know about this. What platform is this issue found? What permissions does your add-in have?

Comment: @OutlookWebAddinsTeam I am getting this issue on OWA and outlook for windows platforms. I gave the "ReadWriteItem" permission in Addin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/preview/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=preview#displaynewappointmentformparameters) is only supported in AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface. It is not supported in AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface.

Comment: I think it's not mentioned in the documentation.